# On Click, Change search icon to Close icon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search icon set up with `after` class:

```
a.mkhb-textbox-el__link:after {
    width: 23.2px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #38445d;
    content: '';
    -webkit-mask: url(/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/search.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    mask: url(/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/search.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 30px;
    vertical-align: -50px !important;
    height: 57px;
}
```

On click it shows search input section:

```
$(document).on("click", ".mkhb-textbox-el__link", function() {

     $( ".search-section" ).slideDown("500" , function() {

     });

  });
```

Is it any way to change `search.svg` to `close.svg`, when calling `on click` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control mask attribute with a separate class and remove/add it when you need:

```
a.mkhb-textbox-el__link:after {
  width: 23.2px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #38445d;
  content: '';
  -webkit-mask: url(/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/search.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  mask: url(/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/search.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 30px;
  vertical-align: -50px !important;
  height: 57px;
}

/* Notice mask url changes here */
a.mkhb-textbox-el__link.close:after {
  -webkit-mask: url(/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/close.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  mask: url(/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/close.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

In JS:

```
$(document).on("click", ".mkhb-textbox-el__link", function() {

 $( ".search-section" ).slideDown("500" , function() {
     $('a.mkhb-textbox-el__link').addClass('close');
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it as follows:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".mkhb-textbox-el__link", function() {

       $( ".search-section" ).slideDown("500" , function() {
       $("#element_id").css("mask", "url(/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/close.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%");
     }); 

  });
```